# I need a grep command that will pull the usernames only from the /etc/passwd file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I need a grep or another like command that will pull the usernames only from the /etc/passwd file in linux.  Anything before the colon. I know this is doing with reg ex however I am not nearly experienced enough...
The following command will give all ACTUAL users, I need a way to pipe to grep or another line of code to only display the username portion.

```
awk -v LIMIT=500 -F: '{print $1}' '($3>=LIMIT) && ($3!=65534)' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Post some sample input and expected output.

Comment: The code you have there looks like it will print every username in your passwd file (and additionally print the entirety of every line that matches your criteria). I imagine you wanted to invert the order of your `{}` and `()` blocks.

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
awk -F: '$3>=LIMIT && $3!=65534 {print $1}' LIMIT=500 /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this in mostly plain bash:

```
limit=500
nfsnobody_id=65534
cut -d: -f1,3 /etc/passwd | while IFS=: read username uid; do
    (( uid >= limit && uid != nfsnobody_id )) && echo $username
done
```

Get out of the habit of using VARNAMES_IN_CAPS: one day you'll write `PATH=$(dirname $FILE)` and then wonder why commands can no longer be found.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to rewrite the filter part of your awk command a bit. For instance, the following should work:

```
awk -v LIMIT=500 -F: '{if (($3>=LIMIT) && ($3!=65534)) print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

Otherwise, to answer your question strictly, if you want to use grep, the command would be

```
   ... | grep -o "^[^:]*"
```

but that would not be the way to go.